# Drawing millions of points in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, cloud, point

I need to visualize a point cloud that consists of millions of 3D points on a WPF window.

Since it's going to have many points, a performance matters, but I don't need to draw any advanced primitives such as triangles, quads, or bitmaps.

After investigation, I came up with some keywords like D3D, D3DRS_POINTSIZE, and D3DImage interop with the combination of native codes and managede codes, but it sounds overkill for my simple goal, and I'm not sure if it is a right thing to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Well, I think that, if you have Expression Blend installed in your machine, you can try to draw it there and then copy the XAML.

Comment: @Default I want to know if what I'm thinking is a right approach.

Comment: @Sonhja I believe XAML Viewport3D has no support of point primitives. What am I missing?

Comment: If you want to draw only points you can use `System.Drawing.Point` . I was only suggesting if Expression had it. Look this link: 
http://www.thejoyofcode.com/using_binding_to_position_a_collection_of_elements.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I don't want to sound rude, but why don't you just try?
You can do the same job in winforms using the right libraries, and WPF has also great graphics libraries but both of them rely on .net framework.

Unmmanged code will probably be more efficient because you will handle only the necessary low-level libraries, butif you are not so handy with C++, then try with .net

Comment: Thanks Jorge. Yes of course I can try, but looking at the sample code for WPF D3D Interop [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591491.aspx), it consists of a bunch of source files along with native c++ projects. To draw triangles, just a couple of XAML lines was enough to do so. For drawing points, D3D Interop is the only and the right approach?